# A module of finite type and localization

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

The following question was asked in my assignment of Introduction to commutative algebra and I was not able to solve this particular problem.

Actually, I am not very good in localization of Modules. So, I am asking for help here.

> Question: Let A be a commutative ring and $S \subset A$ is a multiplicative set.
> (a) Let S has no zero divisors. Show that if $S^{-1}A$  is an A-module of finite type, then $S^{-1} A=A$ ie S contains invertible elements.

(b) Let $A_1= A/I$ and $S_1$ be the image of S in $A_1$ . Show that there exists an isomorphism $S^{-1} A \to {S_1}^{-1} A_1$.

(c)$S^{-1} A$ is an A-module of finite type iff $S_1\subset A^{\times}_1$ and in this case $S^{-1} A $ is isomorphic to A/I.

Attempt: (a) Any element of $S^{-1} A$ is of the form a/s and as $S^{-1} A$ is an A -module of finite type, so, $x\in  S^{-1} A$ implies $x= a/s = {a_1}' \frac{a_1} {s_1} +... + \frac{a_n} {s_n} {a_n}' $ ${a_i}' \in A$ and $\frac{a_i} {s_n} \in A \S$( Definition of finite type).

Now, I have to show that for any $s \in S$ , If inverse of s exists ( call it s') then $s'\in S$.

But I am not able to make any progress.

(b) So,$S_1= S/I$ . Now an element of $S^{-1} A$ is given by a/s , where $a\in A$ and $s\in S$ and an element of ${S_1 }=  s+I $ and an element of $A_1$ is given by $a+I$. $ f : \frac{a} {s} \to \frac{a'+ I} {s' +I}$.  f is onto. I am not able to prove f to be 1-1. Can you please help me with this?

(c) I don't have much to show as attempt in this as well.

Please help me.

Comment: In (b) and (c), you don't specify what $I$ is.  If it's an arbitrary ideal, then (b) and (c) are false.  Did you mean to define $I=\{\,a\in A\mid sa=0 \text{ for some }s\in S\,\}$?

Answer (score 2):

Let me do the first one for you.

So, assume that $S^{-1}A$ is a finitely generated module over $A$. So pick a set of generators $y_i=a_i/s$ for some $a_i\in A, s\in S$. (Do you see why we can choose a common denominator $s$?) Let $t\in S$. Then $1/ts\in S^{-1} A$, so we can write it as $$1/ts= \sum b_iy_i$$ for some $b_i\in A$. Multiply by $ts$ to get $$1= t(\sum a_ib_i)$$ showing $t$ is a unit.

Comment: "Do you see why we can choose a common denominator s?"  Yes as A is a A-module and  $S\subseteq A$.

Comment: Can you please give hints for (c) and (d) ? (a) is clear to me and thank you for that!

Comment: @3ibfwcbi As stated (b) is wrong. The first $A$ should be $A_1$. Same for (c). I do not see a (d).

Comment: I really think you should delete your answer. This answer is not useful.